# Is pass by reference supported in php 7?

Tags: syntax-error, pass-by-reference, php-7

Recently we migrated PHP 5.6 to PHP 7

and now following code throws  `$this->a =& new test($this->f);`

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW)
```

any ideas? what are the alternation that I could use for it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the PHP7 incompatible changes: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

> New objects cannot be assigned by reference
>
> The result of the new statement can no longer be assigned to a
> variable by reference: `<?php class C {} $c =& new C; ?>`
>
> Output of the above example in PHP 5:
>
> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
> deprecated in /tmp/test.php on line 3
>
> Output of the above example in PHP 7:
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /tmp/test.php
> on line 3

There is no alternative. You were using deprecated behavior, and now it's no longer valid PHP. Simply don't assign by reference.

Answer (score 5):

To clarify Marc B's answer: just remove the ampersand like this

```
$this->a = new test($this->f);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this as alternative:

```
$test = new test($this->f);
$this->a = $test;
```

now the $test is passed by reference and if you change attributes of $this->a, $test attributes will also change. and conversely.

**PHP 7 is "pass by reference" by default.** if you don't want to pass an object by it's reference, you should do this:

```
$a = clone $b;
```