# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) and It's always because of "=&"

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error, php-7

Always get this error on ispmanager. I'm using PHP 7.1 and I always get this error because there an "&=" or "=&" in a statement and these errors keep popping up, but not at the same time which is annoying. I always fix an error and I see 5 more pop up.

Is there anyway I can allow "=&" or "=&" in the PHP.ini or something?

```
function __construct($path, $create = false, $mode = 0755) {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->Folder =& new Folder(dirname($path), $create, $mode);
}
```

There's an example.

The error is always in a .php file and always says this "mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in..."

What can I do about this so I don't have to jump through hundreds of files tackling pop-up errors?

Note: I did not make the program I'm looking at rn, I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: To "fix" this code, you'll have to edit the file and drop the `&`.  It should just be `$this->Folder = new Folder(...)`;.

Comment: If this code doesn't work in PHP 7, you may want to look for a new version.  If there is no new version, then you may want to find a new library/script to use instead.

Comment: The most of my problem is there's a lot of files that have this error, so is the any way besides manually removing?

Comment: Unfortunately, manually removing the `&` is the only way.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711215

Comment: @RocketHazmat Isn't there an old version that supports it or do I have to go newer?

Comment: You'd have to downgrade PHP to a version before 7 (5.6, I guess).  This is not recommended as these old PHP versions are no longer supported or getting security updates.  If you can find PHP 5.6, then you can use this old code.  See: https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: I'd suggest retiring this ancient code and finding a new version of it or a new library to do what this one is doing.  It may be time to re-build this site with modern PHP 7.

Comment: To be clear: the `&` here last did something useful in **PHP 4**. It started outputting "E_STRICT" notices in PHP 5.0, and "E_DEPRECATED" notices in PHP 5.3, you just had them disabled or logged to a file you never read. You've had **15 years** to remove it, and now your time's up.

Comment: On the plus side, now you know what causes the error, you don't have to wait for it to pop up each time, you can search the code for everywhere that uses that syntax and fix it.